# Why there are so many different basepoint in lightning network?

Tags: lightning-network

Here are the scripts found in BOLT 03.

Offered HTLC Outputs:

[image]

2nd stage output script:

[image]

Why not just use one pubkey, like localpubkey?

Answer (score 1):

The split is intentional, and allows for trustless watching of revoked transactions, which is often outsourced with the help of watchtowers.

From Bolt3

> Splitting the `local_delayedpubkey`, which is required for the penalty transaction, allows it to be shared with the watcher without revealing `localpubkey`; even if both peers use the same watcher, nothing is revealed.